# Create a sequence using space as delimiter

Tags: expl3

`expl3` swallow spaces but I wonder to build a sequence using space as a delimiter.  So if I want to print '!' after each item the output should be '**A!simple!sentence!has!only!one!clause!**'.

The current MWE gives '**A!s!i!m!p!l!e!s!e!n!t!e!n!c!e!h!a!s!o!n!l!y!o!n!e!c!l!a!u!s!e!.!**'.

Here is my MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse,expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \l_style_list_seq

\NewDocumentCommand{\test}{m}
 {%
  % This won't work
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_style_list_seq { } {#1}

  \seq_map_inline:Nn { \l_style_list_seq }
   {
    ##1!
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
 \test{A simple sentence has only one clause.}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\seq_set_split:Nnn \l_style_list_seq {~} {#1}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wanted space tokens in the programming environment can be specified with `~`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse,expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \l_style_list_seq

\NewDocumentCommand{\test}{m}
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_style_list_seq { ~ } {#1}
  \seq_map_inline:Nn { \l_style_list_seq }
   {
    ##1!
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\test{A simple sentence has only one clause.}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that the replacement text will contain a *real* space token, that is, character code 32 and category code 10, because TeX does this normalization of category code 10 tokens.

Answer (score 2):

I realize the question was about `expl3`.  But it doesn't hurt to do it the old fashioned way.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\test[1]{\testengine#1 \relax}
\def\testengine#1 #2\relax{#1!\if\relax#2\relax\else\testengine#2\relax\fi}
\begin{document}
\test{A simple sentence has only one clause.}
\end{document}
```

[image]